# make href in Latex change color when hover above text

Tags: hyperlink, computer-vision, hover, latex, href

Does anyone know how to make a link change color when hover above it in Latex?
For example, I have `welcome to \href{https://www.google.com}{Google}`
I want it to appear like normal text (does not have any effect) `welcome to Google`
But when I hover the word `Google` , it will turn blue.

Comment: Have a look at [fancytooltip](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancytooltips?lang=en). But, AFAIK, the effect will only be visible in acrobat reader, as it is the only reader that can  interpret javascript code embedded in a pdf file.

Comment: thanks for the advice about acrobat reader. I did look at fancytooltip, but I still don't know how to make the text turn blue when hovering above it. Can you give me an example?